# Using Parse.com with Phonegap; Trouble with user registration

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, cordova, parse-platform

I'm building an Android application using Phonegap and Parse.com to aid in "database" management. I have an html form to hold user "username" and user "password" with a submit input button with id "adduserbutton".

Here is my login.html form. (Note, this html file is referencing a file named "main.js" which stores the logic behind registering a user.

```
            <form id ="adduser">
            <label for="text-3">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" id="username" id="text-3" placeHolder="Enter Desired Username">

            <label for="text-3">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" id="password" id="text-3" placeholder="Enter Desired Password">

            <input type="submit" id="adduserbutton" value="Add User">
            </form>
```

This form will take username and password (not hashed yet, simply testing at this moment). 
Main.js sits waiting for "adduserbutton" to be clicked, and should then run a function. This is where the trouble is, so here is my main.js code:

```
//Parse related keys
var PARSE_APP = "hidden for sake of post";
var PARSE_JS = "hidden for sake of post";

$(document).ready(function() {
Parse.initialize(PARSE_APP, PARSE_JS);

var user = new Parse.User();

$("#adduserbutton").on("touchend", function(e) {
alert("here");
e.preventDefault();

//Grab the user details, no real validation for now
var username = $("#username").val();
user.set("username", username);
var password = $("#password").val();
user.set("password", password);

user.signUp(null, {
           success: function(user) {
               alert("it worked")
           },
           error: function(user, error) {
               alert("error");
           }
    });

  });
```

As you can see, what 'should' be happening here is:

1. User types in desired username & password, clicks submit button.
2. "adduserbutton" is clicked, firing main.js to store data?
3. username and password form text fields stored into user Parse object.
4. User registered into my Parse table.

Yet, I click the submit button, the page flashes (seems to refresh), and nothing happens. No errors, and nothing is showing up in my database. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known bug with the touchend depending the android version you are using:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827

Otherwise I can only recomend the use of some tools for debugging:

[Ripple emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en)

and the chrome tools for developers to debug and see if the

$("#adduserbutton").on("touchend", function(e) fires at all. Dosen't seem to be a parse thing and I guess your API request that Parse recived is 0 or at least not increasing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue!

Changed my js line in Main.js from:

```
$("#adduserbutton").on("touchend", function(e) {
alert("here");
e.preventDefault();
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('adduserbutton').onclick = function() {
```